# iOS 11.0 GM: Subviews of UINavigationItem's titleView don't receive touch events?

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In all versions of iOS — including every beta of iOS 11.0 except the GM, 15A372 — views inside of a `UINavigationItem`'s `titleView` would receive touch events as normal, making it possible to have buttons in the title view.

In build 15A372, subviews of the `titleView` do not receive any touch events, so buttons in that view are useless. I've tested with both devices and Simulators running iOS 10 and don't see this behavior. I've opened `rdar://34499607` about this and will update this question when I hear back, but I want to know if anyone else has encountered this, or has any temporary solutions.

Apple's [documentation about the `titleView` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview) specifically notes that "custom views can contain buttons," making this a confusing change.

If this is the intended behavior, it's infuriating that they've waited until the almost-literal eleventh hour to make this significant change and neglect to include it in any documentation or release notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this question [link](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000010999970/a-1020000011055505)

Comment: Thanks! Though it was in Chinese, this link had exactly what I was looking for. For anyone else with this issue, the problem was that the `titleView`'s height was being set to 0. Subclassing `UIView` and overriding `intrinsicContentSize` allowed me to resize the `titleView`, allowing touches to be received again.

Answer (score 3):

Just override  intrinsicContentSize property in your view:

import UIKit

class HeaderView: UIView {

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 400, height: 55)
}
```

}

Comment: Like I said in my comment on the accepted answer, this is correct.